Life of a man and woman are connected by an arm gauntlet thingy
This is a movie/tv show that I saw when I was really little so bear with me:

This could be a movie or made-for-TV movie (English)
Saw it back during the very early 2000s or late 90s.
Setting: Possibly middle ages as the clothes seem to suggest that.
It is not animated.
Plot: A man wears an arm guantlet similar to what Hercules wears on his arms:


But I think it is more of a baige color with fancy styling. This item is supposed to be unbreakable and the man is forced to wear this for the rest of his life (I believe). The man falls in love with a woman and then somehow later on I think the gauntlet makes him weak and he has to break it off. Either that or someone tries to break off the gauntlet which makes both the man and woman weaker (very foggy on this part).
They also got the gauntlet off.
That is all I really have. If you have any questions or need clarification I will try to give a good response.
P.S. I don't know if gauntlet is the correct word for what he's wearing.

Perhaps you mean the Kor mak bracelets from Stargate SG-1. From the Wikia page:

Kor mak bracelets are a pair of bracelets that link the wearers. If the two wearing the bracelets should get more than one hundred feet from each other, they will begin to feel ill. Cronus used them when he wanted his Jaffa to transport a prisoner. If the prisoner escaped, they would both be killed by the bracelets, punishing the Jaffa for his incompetence

The bracelets appear in the 2-part episode Avalon, where a man and a woman were connected by them (and medieval outfits abound in the planet they're on). Here's the trailer:



And here's the bracelet:


Hmm...I'm going to try to look up some scenes but the description sounds like it matches.

I remember them wearing old style clothing as if they were in Game of Thrones. And I remember the bracelet being much wider and having a lighter color.

Added an episode trailer. See if you recognize anything.

I'm on a mobile so I don't have the plugin for the video. Anything on YT? :(

Here's the Youtube link.

Is there a scene where the bracelet comes off?

Yes, they do come off in the next episode.
